# Angular Client - Access Token Fail Authenication

Tags: asp.net-identity, identity, identityserver4

I have a Angular Client that I'm able to login into the Identity Server (Implicit) using the username and password.  See screenshots below:[image]

Upon login in I get the following info:

[image]

When I click on the API button the following code is executed:

[image]

Answer Posted Below (Thanks to m3n7alsnak3 - see comments below):

API Startup class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Constants;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

namespace Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        #region "Startup"
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        #endregion

        #region "ConfigureServices"
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddAuthorization(options =>
                {
                    options.AddPolicy("JsClient", config =>
                    {
                        config.RequireClaim("client_id", "js");
                    });
                })
                .AddJsonFormatters();

            #region "services.AddAuthentication"
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = Constants.Constant.AuthServer;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                });
            #endregion

            #region "Commented out services.AddCors"
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("default", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5003")
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });
            #endregion
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Configure"
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseCors("default");

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

IDS Startup Code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using AuthServer.Data;
using AuthServer.Models;
using AuthServer.Services;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Constants;

namespace AuthServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        #region "Startup"
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        #endregion

        #region "ConfigureServices"
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

            services.AddMvc();

            string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                // this adds the config data from DB (clients, resources)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    //options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    //options.TokenCleanupInterval = 15; // interval in seconds. 15 seconds useful for debugging
                });

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
                {
                    options.ClientId = "434483408261-55tc8n0cs4ff1fe21ea8df2o443v2iuc.apps.googleusercontent.com";
                    options.ClientSecret = "3gcoTrEDPPJ0ukn_aYYT6PWo";
                });
        }
        #endregion

        #region "Configure"
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            // app.UseAuthentication(); // not needed, since UseIdentityServer adds the authentication middleware
            app.UseIdentityServer();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

API Log:

```
  Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AuthServer\Api
Now listening on: http://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 OPTIONS http://localhost:5001/identity
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 84.7188ms 204
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5001/identity
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService[4]
      Policy execution successful.
[13:39:14 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
Successfully validated the token.

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[2]
      Successfully validated the token.
[13:39:14 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler
AuthenticationScheme: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was successfully authenticated.

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: BearerIdentityServerAuthenticationJwt was successfully authenticated.
[13:39:14 Information] IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.

info: IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationHandler[8]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was successfully authenticated.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[1]
      Authorization was successful for user: prdiet.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[1]
      Executing action method Api.Controllers.IdentityController.Get (Api) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json.Internal.JsonResultExecutor[1]
      Executing JsonResult, writing value System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Security.Claims.Claim,<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.String]].
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Api.Controllers.IdentityController.Get (Api) in 224.2595ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 2045.1953ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

IDS Log:

```
2018-02-09 13:37:41.253 -05:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default scheme for authentication
2018-02-09 13:37:41.338 -05:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default scheme for sign-in
2018-02-09 13:37:41.342 -05:00 [DBG] Using Identity.External as default scheme for sign-out
2018-02-09 13:37:41.346 -05:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default scheme for challenge
2018-02-09 13:37:41.349 -05:00 [DBG] Using Identity.Application as default scheme for forbid
2018-02-09 13:38:20.503 -05:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:38:21.589 -05:00 [DBG] Origin http://localhost:5003 is allowed: true
2018-02-09 13:38:21.604 -05:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:38:21.729 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2018-02-09 13:38:21.778 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:38:21.785 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2018-02-09 13:38:21.801 -05:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2018-02-09 13:38:23.306 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","email","profile","api1.IdentityScope","admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] as all scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:23.535 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
2018-02-09 13:38:23.635 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:38:23.640 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
2018-02-09 13:38:23.658 -05:00 [DBG] Start authorize request
2018-02-09 13:38:23.687 -05:00 [DBG] No user present in authorize request
2018-02-09 13:38:23.714 -05:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2018-02-09 13:38:24.970 -05:00 [DBG] js found in database: true
2018-02-09 13:38:25.192 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:25.629 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] API scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:25.797 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:26.099 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] API scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:26.136 -05:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-02-09 13:38:26.200 -05:00 [INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
  "ClientId": "js",
  "ClientName": "js.client",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:5003/callback.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "ResponseType": "id_token token",
  "ResponseMode": "fragment",
  "GrantType": "implicit",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile api1",
  "State": "2e1163f138514b2ab6d9b3da5cca4a03",
  "Nonce": "d5a791d91e664b28a021b589307cc6a9",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "js",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    "response_type": "id_token token",
    "scope": "openid profile api1",
    "state": "2e1163f138514b2ab6d9b3da5cca4a03",
    "nonce": "d5a791d91e664b28a021b589307cc6a9"
  }
}
2018-02-09 13:38:26.232 -05:00 [INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
2018-02-09 13:38:26.881 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
2018-02-09 13:38:26.913 -05:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2018-02-09 13:38:27.728 -05:00 [DBG] js found in database: true
2018-02-09 13:38:27.883 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:28.250 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] API scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:28.408 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:28.788 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] API scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:38:28.796 -05:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-02-09 13:38:57.996 -05:00 [DBG] Augmenting SignInContext
2018-02-09 13:38:58.004 -05:00 [DBG] Adding idp claim with value: local
2018-02-09 13:38:58.008 -05:00 [DBG] Adding amr claim with value: pwd
2018-02-09 13:38:58.016 -05:00 [DBG] Adding auth_time claim with value: 1518201538
2018-02-09 13:38:58.040 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
2018-02-09 13:38:58.049 -05:00 [INF] User logged in.
2018-02-09 13:38:58.109 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2018-02-09 13:38:58.119 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2018-02-09 13:38:58.129 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/authorize/callback matched to endpoint type Authorize
2018-02-09 13:38:58.136 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:38:58.143 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
2018-02-09 13:38:58.163 -05:00 [DBG] Start authorize callback request
2018-02-09 13:38:58.179 -05:00 [DBG] User in authorize request: 8ae24a28-59f5-48a6-92c6-c6cac551341b
2018-02-09 13:38:58.184 -05:00 [DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
2018-02-09 13:38:59.378 -05:00 [DBG] js found in database: true
2018-02-09 13:38:59.598 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:00.165 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] API scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:00.406 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:01.020 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] API scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:01.032 -05:00 [DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
2018-02-09 13:39:01.037 -05:00 [INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
  "ClientId": "js",
  "ClientName": "js.client",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "http://localhost:5003/callback.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "8ae24a28-59f5-48a6-92c6-c6cac551341b",
  "ResponseType": "id_token token",
  "ResponseMode": "fragment",
  "GrantType": "implicit",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile api1",
  "State": "2e1163f138514b2ab6d9b3da5cca4a03",
  "Nonce": "d5a791d91e664b28a021b589307cc6a9",
  "SessionId": "f80b09fa34fe67f90117912fb01ee854",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "js",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    "response_type": "id_token token",
    "scope": "openid profile api1",
    "state": "2e1163f138514b2ab6d9b3da5cca4a03",
    "nonce": "d5a791d91e664b28a021b589307cc6a9"
  }
}
2018-02-09 13:39:01.263 -05:00 [DBG] Client is configured to not require consent, no consent is required
2018-02-09 13:39:01.284 -05:00 [DBG] Creating Implicit Flow response.
2018-02-09 13:39:01.311 -05:00 [DBG] Getting claims for access token for client: js
2018-02-09 13:39:01.317 -05:00 [DBG] Getting claims for access token for subject: 8ae24a28-59f5-48a6-92c6-c6cac551341b
2018-02-09 13:39:01.722 -05:00 [DBG] Getting claims for identity token for subject: 8ae24a28-59f5-48a6-92c6-c6cac551341b and client: js
2018-02-09 13:39:01.729 -05:00 [DBG] In addition to an id_token, an access_token was requested. No claims other than sub are included in the id_token. To obtain more user claims, either use the user info endpoint or set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken on the client configuration.
2018-02-09 13:39:01.775 -05:00 [INF] Authorize endpoint response
{
  "SubjectId": "8ae24a28-59f5-48a6-92c6-c6cac551341b",
  "ClientId": "js",
  "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
  "State": "2e1163f138514b2ab6d9b3da5cca4a03",
  "Scope": "openid profile api1"
}
2018-02-09 13:39:01.824 -05:00 [DBG] Augmenting SignInContext
2018-02-09 13:39:01.829 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in.
2018-02-09 13:39:02.256 -05:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:02.334 -05:00 [DBG] Origin http://localhost:5003 is allowed: true
2018-02-09 13:39:02.340 -05:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:02.362 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2018-02-09 13:39:02.372 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:02.392 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2018-02-09 13:39:02.416 -05:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2018-02-09 13:39:02.852 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","email","profile","api1.IdentityScope","admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] as all scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:02.879 -05:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks from origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:02.934 -05:00 [DBG] Origin http://localhost:5003 is allowed: true
2018-02-09 13:39:02.940 -05:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:02.950 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery
2018-02-09 13:39:02.957 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:02.962 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
2018-02-09 13:39:02.980 -05:00 [DBG] Start key discovery request
2018-02-09 13:39:03.093 -05:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /connect/userinfo from origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:03.148 -05:00 [DBG] Origin http://localhost:5003 is allowed: true
2018-02-09 13:39:03.154 -05:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:03.192 -05:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /connect/userinfo from origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:03.250 -05:00 [DBG] Origin http://localhost:5003 is allowed: true
2018-02-09 13:39:03.257 -05:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:03.273 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/userinfo matched to endpoint type Userinfo
2018-02-09 13:39:03.289 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Userinfo, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:03.296 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.UserInfoEndpoint for /connect/userinfo
2018-02-09 13:39:03.318 -05:00 [DBG] Start userinfo request
2018-02-09 13:39:03.330 -05:00 [DBG] Bearer token found in header
2018-02-09 13:39:04.059 -05:00 [DBG] js found in database: true
2018-02-09 13:39:04.621 -05:00 [DBG] js found in database: true
2018-02-09 13:39:04.702 -05:00 [DBG] Calling into custom token validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomTokenValidator
2018-02-09 13:39:04.722 -05:00 [DBG] Token validation success
{
  "ValidateLifetime": true,
  "AccessTokenType": "Jwt",
  "ExpectedScope": "openid",
  "Claims": {
    "nbf": 1518201541,
    "exp": 1518205141,
    "iss": "http://localhost:5000",
    "aud": [
      "http://localhost:5000/resources",
      "api1"
    ],
    "client_id": "js",
    "sub": "8ae24a28-59f5-48a6-92c6-c6cac551341b",
    "auth_time": 1518201538,
    "idp": "local",
    "name": "prdiet",
    "email": "Paul.Dietz@roush.com",
    "scope": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "api1"
    ],
    "amr": "pwd"
  }
}
2018-02-09 13:39:04.745 -05:00 [DBG] Creating userinfo response
2018-02-09 13:39:04.761 -05:00 [DBG] Scopes in access token: openid profile api1
2018-02-09 13:39:04.773 -05:00 [DBG] Scopes in access token: openid profile api1
2018-02-09 13:39:04.896 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:04.905 -05:00 [DBG] Requested claim types: sub zoneinfo birthdate gender website picture profile locale preferred_username middle_name given_name family_name name nickname updated_at
2018-02-09 13:39:04.911 -05:00 [DBG] Scopes in access token: openid profile api1
2018-02-09 13:39:05.006 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","profile"] identity scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:05.139 -05:00 [INF] Profile service returned to the following claim types: sub preferred_username name
2018-02-09 13:39:05.149 -05:00 [DBG] End userinfo request
2018-02-09 13:39:05.200 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2018-02-09 13:39:05.217 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2018-02-09 13:39:05.228 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/checksession matched to endpoint type Checksession
2018-02-09 13:39:05.237 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Checksession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:05.244 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession
2018-02-09 13:39:05.255 -05:00 [DBG] Rendering check session result
2018-02-09 13:39:05.538 -05:00 [DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:05.608 -05:00 [DBG] Origin http://localhost:5003 is allowed: true
2018-02-09 13:39:05.613 -05:00 [DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:5003
2018-02-09 13:39:05.624 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2018-02-09 13:39:05.632 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:05.637 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2018-02-09 13:39:05.646 -05:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2018-02-09 13:39:06.042 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","email","profile","api1.IdentityScope","admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] as all scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:06.082 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2018-02-09 13:39:06.092 -05:00 [INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2018-02-09 13:39:06.102 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /connect/checksession matched to endpoint type Checksession
2018-02-09 13:39:06.108 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Checksession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:06.114 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession
2018-02-09 13:39:06.125 -05:00 [DBG] Rendering check session result
2018-02-09 13:39:13.278 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
2018-02-09 13:39:13.284 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:13.290 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
2018-02-09 13:39:13.298 -05:00 [DBG] Start discovery request
2018-02-09 13:39:13.703 -05:00 [DBG] Found ["openid","email","profile","api1.IdentityScope","admin","user","api1.APIScope","api1"] as all scopes in database
2018-02-09 13:39:14.217 -05:00 [DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks matched to endpoint type Discovery
2018-02-09 13:39:14.223 -05:00 [DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint
2018-02-09 13:39:14.229 -05:00 [INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryKeyEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
2018-02-09 13:39:14.238 -05:00 [DBG] Start key discovery request
```

Fiddle test results:
[image]

Finally the API response:

[image]

Comment: If AccessTokenType in the EF Identity DB Clients table  is set to 0, does that indicate a reference or self-contained token type?  I want to insure that it set to self-contained token type in this case...

Comment: When and why would I need to use the PairWiseSubjectSalt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines that you have mentioned

> .AddJwtBearer to services.AddAuthentication()
>
> Services.AddAuthorization

should be part of your API `Startup.cs`, not part of the Identity Server one's.

And also the policy should be, again, specified in the API and not in the IDS.

Why is that? By using `services.AddAuthentication()` (whatever type, in your case is JWTBearer) you are saying:

> Hey, this resources are protected, please authenticate against `authority` to be able to access it.

Then comes the authorization part, that is again your API's responsibility, and not IDS'. The policy, that you specifies, is API specific, that means:

> Hey, you are authenticated against that authority, but I have some more requirements/rules to let you in.

And there you specify the rules. You can treat the Policy-Based authorization as an advanced Role-Based or more like custom authorization attribute, but the important part - it is API's responsibility.

Start from there, and see what happens then.

**EDIT**

Based on our discussion, I'm updating the answer. Now try switching your API startup to the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services
        .AddMvcCore()
        .AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            // your policies
        })

    // more code 

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
        .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = <ids address>;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });

    // more code
```

Keep the stuff around it. And be careful - in your test scenario 2, you had a 2 times `services.AddAuthorization()`. Do it only once (as shown above). Give it a try.

**EDIT 2**

In `services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")` - Bearer is with capital (upper case) `B`!

Comment: I made some pretty good progress based on your recommandations.  Now I'm getting a 401 at the API.  API is not able to route the request to the authserver for the Jwt authentication... Posted the test changes and test results above.

Comment: First thing that I see - in your API startup, you have 2 times services.AddAuthorization(). Mode the logic from the second one in the first one and delete the 2nd. Also - I think that you can remove `config.AddAuthenticationSchemes("bearer");` from the policy configuration. Try this and lets see

Comment: One more thing that I notice - the AddAuthentication in your API startup. The commented out one seems better to me, than the one that you are currently using. Just remove the api name property

Comment: Updated the information above. I'm getting back a 500 error code now.  Can we pick this up tomorrow... I think we're making progress.  P

Comment: I've ran several tests this morning.  Basically found that if I use the Identity Server Authentication the API throws a 500 exception.  If I use the Jwt Bear Authentication the API sends a 401 error.

Comment: No I just posted Test 3.  Hopefully I'm making progress.  Otherwise I can go back to Test 2.  Just made a small change in the API Startup class.  Let me know what you think.. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164848/discussion-between-m3n7alsnak3-and-paul).

Comment: I made the suggested changes and posted them along with the test result API log file above.  Still receive a 500 error...  Do I need app.UseCors("default"); in API Startup Configuration section.

Comment: Answer updated. I think that this is the reason - I was able to repro your problem.

Comment: Your a genius... It's working now!  I have one last question for you regarding the API call.  If I want the angular client to automatically call the API after the user login, were would you suggest I implement the API button click logic?  Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Should be after the callback from Identity Server is completed, because before that you don't have the tokens. Could be in the `then()` of the callback function too.

PS: Please mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: Thanks for everything... I updated the documentation above and accepted your answer.  Have a great weekend.